# Is there the SUMIF() function that works returning text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used `SUMIF()` before to return the value (number) in one column by searching through text in another column, but can I do the reverse? For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Table | 1234 |
| Style | 5678 |
| Bold | 9012 |

```
somefunction(B1:B5, 1234, A1:A5) = “Table”
```

I tried regular `SUMIF()` on this but it didn't work...
Any help please?

Comment: `XLOOKUP` or `INDEX`+`MATCH`.

Comment: Look here solutions in StackOverflow : **[XLOOKUP()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+XLOOKUP)** or **[INDEX()+MATCH()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4851590+INDEX+MATCH)**

Comment: Are values unique in the columns?

Comment: @Blackcat usually, if not then first one will work

Comment: Those solution links where the answers are given by @ScottCraner sir certainly it will work, there are whole lotta bunch of `INDEX()` + `MATCH()` and `XLOOKUP()` solutions good link to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya) for your comment, I ended up using `XLOOKUP()` *(which I never knew about before)*

**For people looking for my code:**
`XLOOKUP(1234,B1:B3,A1:A3,"",0,1)`